# Is spice-vdagent required for Wayland?

Tags: xorg, wayland

I noticed the following message in syslog:

> Cannot access vdagent virtio channel
>   /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0

I am running Ubuntu 18.10 on Wayland, so could I delete spice-vdagent? And if I did what effect would that have if I decided to run Ubuntu 18.10 under Xorg?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu in a VM? Spice is one of a few protocols or technologies using which a virtual machine can communicate with its host to e.g. provide a shared clipboard or allow resizing the screen when you resize the host window. If you run Ubuntu on bare metal, you don't get anything useful from `spice-vdagent`.

Comment: Maybe of interest: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/spice-vdagent/+bug/1800196

Comment: @ByteCommander It's not clear (to me) that spice-vdagent is for the client alone - it seems that it might be used on the host also, to provide host to client transfers of the clipboard and such.

Comment: @Byte Commander. No, I am running Ubuntu 18.10 as the only OS on a new Corei7 laptop.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I disagree, what you need on the host is not the `spice-vdagent` but a spice-compatible client, like e.g. `virt-viewer`. I can not find any use for the agent outside a virtualized guest system.

Comment: @ByteCommander I wonder why the packagers cause it to be installed default.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Oh. Indeed, seems like in 18.04 and later, `ubuntu-desktop` depends on `spice-vdagent`. 16.04 does not btw. However, I stand by my point claiming that it is useless on bare metal, but I assume they just want to make Ubuntu more VM-friendly out of the box. IMO it should be a recommended package instead though, no required dependency. Wonder why they decided on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`spice-vdagent` is used only in virtualized guest systems to provide features like sharing the clipboard with the host/client or dynamically resizing the virtual screen together with the client window. It has no use on bare-metal installations.

The error you describe was:

```
Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
```

This is only natural on a non-virtual system, because `/dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0` is a special device created by compatible hypervisors to provide a spice channel for communication between guest and host/client. It does not exist on hardware, therefore any `spice-vdagent` instance running on a bare-metal system can not find such a device.

You can safely uninstall this package from your system, as you don't need it because it is not a virtual machine:

```
sudo apt purge spice-vdagent
```

**Edit:** Actually, on at least 18.04 and newer (not yet on 16.04), `ubuntu-desktop` depends on `spice-vdagent`, so trying to remove that will also uninstall the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage. This would not directly remove your desktop, but it's still not too advisable probably. I wonder why the devs decided to make this a mandatory dependency, but I am still convinced it has no use on a bare-metal installation.

---

From the package's description (extracts only; typos preserved as-is; full output can be obtained by running `apt show spice-vdagent`):

```
Package: spice-vdagent
Homepage: http://www.spice-space.org/
Description: Spice agent for Linux
 spice-vdagent is the spice agent for Linux, it is used in conjunction with
 spice-compitable hypervisor, its feature includs:
 \* Client mouse mode (no need to grab mouse by client, no mouse lag)
   this is handled by the daemon by feeding mouse events into the kernel
   via uinput. This will only work if the active X-session is running a
   spice-vdagent process so that its resolution can be determined.
 \* Automatic adjustment of the X-session resolution to the client resolution
 \* Support of copy and paste (text and images) between the active X-session
   and the client
```

Additional links:

- [General overview on the whole spice technology and architecture](https://www.spice-space.org/static/docs/spice_for_newbies.pdf)
- [Red Hat Virtualization Deployment and Administration Guide - Spice Agent section](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-spice_agent)

Comment: Would I need it if I needed to run Android or Windows emulation software or VMs?

Comment: Not on your host, no. It is only useful inside the virtual machines, if they support it.

Comment: Sorry, i don't quite understand. If I decide to run a VM (or emulation) on my native Ubuntu 18.10 OS, would I need spice-vdagent in order fot the VM to run?

Comment: No. Your Ubuntu host operating system, the one that is directly installed on physical hardware, never needs `spice-vdagent` installed. If you set up a virtual machine on your host, with another Linux system as guest, that guest system would profit from having `spice-vdagent` installed (on the guest system, still not on the host), but it would still run without the package. It just adds a few convenient features, as I described in the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried `sudo apt purge spice-vdagent` - I did not however, want to remove ubuntu-desktop and gnome-desktop....

Comment: It's only useful inside VMs that are running under something like KVM/QEMU; VirtualBox and VMware could care less about spice-vdagent. This package should have never been set as a hard dependency to ubuntu-desktop. @ByteCommander - you are 100% correct - completely useless on bare-metal installs.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see the need to have spice-vdagent installed (that I understand is for virtual machine guest)

Finally, I found a solution confirming the way to disable it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/spice-vdagent/+bug/1800196/comments/29):

> Basically adding the line:
>
> ```
> X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
> ```
>
> To the files:
>
> ```
> /etc/xdg/autostart/spice-vdagent.desktop
> /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/spice-vdagent.desktop
> ```
>
> Then stop and disable the service:
>
> ```
> $ sudo systemctl stop spice-vdagentd
> $ sudo systemctl disable spice-vdagentd
> ```

And reboot.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using desktop share, you can uninstall it. Or the next solution is to configure the spice server, and eventually close its startup.

Check here:

- [vdagent message via journalctl occurs alot](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?310792-vdagent-message-via-journalctl-occurs-alot).
- [spice for newbies](https://www.spice-space.org/static/docs/spice_for_newbies.pdf)

In ubuntu 19.04 configuration file you can find here

> /sys/class/virtio-ports